# Code vocabulary statistics

Tags: language-agnostic, vocabulary

A couple of months ago Harvard University and Google researchers did [a study](http://www.boston.com/news/science/articles/2010/12/17/harvard_google_join_in_study_of_books_from_past_200_years/) where they mined the complete text of 4 percent of the world’s books and came out with interesting statistics about the English vocabulary.

Has anyone done something similar for a programming language?

Comment: possibly appropriate for programmers.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a *similar* analysis that was done against massive amounts of code and multiple languages in github: http://corte.si/posts/code/devsurvey/index.html

Also, on a small scale, code analysis and code metrics tools that are used with most IDEs will provide that sort of analysis within a single codebase--spitting out interesting things like cyclomatic complexity, lines of code, etc.--which are *similar* in a way.  Sort of like analyzing a single book instead of a library.